# Why is a Linked list's Node has next as Node type and not an int type

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have to come to understand that this is how we create a simple Linked List in C#

```
public class Node {
public Node next;
public Object data;
}

public class LinkedList
{
    public Node head;
}
```

However, since in the basic Linked List concept, "next" denotes nothing but a pointer to the next node which is simply an address, I do not get a hang around as to why it's data type has to be "Node" and not some bigint or float? Can someone please help me get the basic right.

Comment: Why would it be an bigint or a float? Its a chain of node's, so a node points to the next node, so its next variable is of type node.

Comment: I assune you're coming from C where you have structs and pointer to structs. In C# you don't have an allocation with variable declaration, so its either primitves or 'pointer' in the C-sence

Comment: "`next` denotes nothing but a pointer to the next node which is simply an address" Sure, but all of that memory stuff is handled by the runtime. C# is a higher level language. We don't have to deal with addresses and memory. In the programming language, `next` refers to a `Node`.

Comment: Technically speaking node is a reference / address already, yet C# allows us to deal with them in a typed formalized way as part of the language.

Comment: Were i to write a linked list in C#, it would be a `LinkedList<T>`, and the nodes would be `Node<T>` (same T). The properties of the node would be `Node<T> Next` and `T data`. I'm pretty sure that that is pretty close to how I used to do it in C++ (except, of course that `Next` would be a pointer to the next node and that `Data` might be either a value (like an int or a double) or a pointer to an allocated object. The C# type system takes care of that for me

Comment: there is a lot of valid and good comments here already. Imagine a Node like a Shoe-Box and inside the box are your shoes( your data or value) and Next is not poiting to the next Shoe but to the Box containing those shoes. As FlyDog57 mentions, thats the way to implement these "genric" data structures for type safety etc. in 13 years i never had to use "object" directly only to trick the compiler in rare cases :-O .  yes, memory handling and pointers are "managed" behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

because whatever address the "next" will contain is of type Node, not an int or float type.